# Nuxt 2: PostCSS Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js, postcss, postcss-loader

One of the developers on my team came to me with an error he encountered while building our Nuxt 2.17.3 project. For me this came as a surprise as I never encountered the problem but after following a couple steps I also got the error:

1. Removed node_modules
2. Removed yarn lockfiles
3. Cleaned yarn cache
4. Execute the yarn command

Now we "suddenly" get the following fatal error:

```
Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
```

It looks like the error is with postcss. Even after carefully checking all package versions I can't seem to solve the problem.

The full error is as follows:

```
ERROR in ./assets/scss/master.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./assets/scss/master.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator.SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js:276:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator.SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at /Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js:72:17
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-consumer.js:155:7)
    at Function.SourceMapGenerator_fromSourceMap [as fromSourceMap] (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js:48:24)
    at MapGenerator.generateMap (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss/lib/map-generator.js:101:37)
    at MapGenerator.generate (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss/lib/map-generator.js:85:19)
    at new NoWorkResult (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss/lib/no-work-result.js:33:46)
    at Processor.process (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:51:14)
    at runPostcss (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/process-content.js:48:6)
    at processContent (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/process-content.js:42:10)
    at /Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/postcss-import/index.js:382:20
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async LazyResult.runAsync (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:261:11)
    at async Object.loader (/Users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:95:14)
 @ ./assets/scss/master.scss 4:14-243
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
```

What could be the issue? I'm in despair! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you changed the version of one or more packages that are not compatible with other packages. check postcss package and its loader. check package.json content on the show log of Git

Comment: It seems like there has been some juggling done with versions related to sass-loader and node-sass. The `git show` tip is definitely helpful! Yet reverting back those changes doesn't seem to resolve the problem. It only seems to add new problems...

Comment: I had the same problem with the sass-loader and node-sass versions. your problem is with sass-loader version.

Comment: It's sadly not the sass-loader package. When I downgrade to 10.1.1 I get a warning that Nuxt expects 10.4.1, so when I update to 10.4.1 I get the exact same error without the warning.

Comment: Currently these are the sass related versions:
```
"node-sass": "^8.0.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.5",
"sass-loader": "10.4.1",
"webpack": "^4.46.0"
"tailwindcss": "3.4.1",
"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "6.9.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific issue there was an issue with an imported css file from the `vue-select` package in our `master.scss` file. Hardcoding the contents of the vue-select css file into the master.scss solves the issue.